# How to check visitor that goes to redirected download url for wp logging?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, .htaccess, url, redirect

I'm trying to setup a mediator which checks if a visitor logged into our wordpress site before accessing redirect download link. And if user not logged in do not allow to access that url. There are external direct download urls which are redirected by htaccess rule from http://www.ourwebsite.com/resources url in our website.

I've tried this code but it didn't work. I put it on functions.php:

```
require('../wp-load.php');  // modify to reflect where your PHP file is in relation to Wordpress
$roles = wp_get_current_user()->roles;  // get current users role

if (!in_array('alloweduserrole',$roles)) {  // modify to match your roles that are allowed to download

    header('Location: http://www.ourwebsite.com/');
    exit;

}  // end of if user does not have the proper role
```

I couldn't locate any php file for that. Added above code but nothing happened. Nothing changed.
Maybe i should choose another php file other than wp-load.php ?

Comment: Have you tried printing the $roles variable to see what's inside? There may also be an error, since you're not checking if the user is actually logged in, so wp_get_current_user() may return 0.

Comment: no haven't tried. is this function can intermediate before htaccess redirect rule apply?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with the htaccess rule. Try printing the variable (for both a logged-in and a non logged-in user) and post the results.

Comment: ive used this in ht acces: Redirect 301 /resources https://external.com/download

Comment: Try printing the variable (for both a logged-in and a non logged-in user) and post the results.

Comment: can you pls tell me how can i do that?

Comment: Use this code before the if statement: print_r( $roles ); exit;

Comment: Your rewriting via the .htaccess does its job already, before WordPress or PHP is even given a chance to interfere.

Answer (score 0):

What I have understood from your requirement that, you want to check the logged-in status on WordPress site, and if not you are redirecting the user to another url, right? Correct me if I'm wrong. So if you are checking inside the theme `functions.php`, there is no need of `require('../wp-load.php');`

You can use below code snippet:

```
add_action("init", "check_user");
function check_user() {
  if (! is_user_logged_in()) {
    wp_redirect("your redirect url", 301);
    //You can skip the 301, if the url is not a external link
    exit;
  }
}
```

}

Comment: i have this code in htaccess: Redirect 301 /resources https://external.com/directdownload-     so the wordpress itself should interfere https://www.example.com/resources url redirection and check if the user logged in if not it should be show forbidden error.

Comment: can we check it on htaccess: RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*wordpress_logged_in.*$ [NC]  ?

Comment: @vordinerdo I did not understand your requirement. Please explain me, where do you want to check user logged-in whether its a WordPress site or not the same, where do you want to redirect? Do you have two separate sites?

Comment: two separate sites one is wp other one is perl based i have to check it on redirect or on perl based site or both